# Is this a valid argument for Lipschitz Equivalence i.e. Topologically equivalent metrics?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Here, I saw the exact same question but I am trying to show it with Lipschitz Equivalence, for practice. The question is,
[A problem about topologically equivalent metrics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208591/a-problem-about-topologically-equivalent-metrics)

but I will reiterate.

> I have some metric space $(X,d)$ and another metric $d'=\text{min}\{1,d(x,y)\}$ is defined. Then, show that the metrics $d,d'$ are topologically equivalent.

The Lipschitz equivalence is stated as

> Let $X$ be a set and $d,d'$ be metrics on $X$. We say $d,d'$ are Lipschitz equivalent if there exists $c,C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c,C>0$ and $cd(x,y) \geq d'(x,y) \geq Cd(x,y)$ $\forall x,y \in X$.

And a lemma states(I will omit the proof as it is in my notes)

> Lipschitz equivalent metrics are topologically equivalent.

So, Basically I have attempted to find such $c,C>0$. My answer is,
$c=d(x,y), C=\frac{1}{d(x,y)}$

I think this satisfies the above inequalities $\forall x,y \in X$. My doubt is, well while $d(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}$, I was not sure if I could use the metric in question as my $c$ and $C$.

Is my answer valid? If not, could you please tell me how to find such $C$ and $c$ and what it is in this case?
If it is valid, I'd be more than happy...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that $c$ must be independent of any $x,y\in X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$c$ and $C$ are constant, in particular they cannot depend on $x,y \in X$.

In general, $d$ and $d'$ are not Lipschitz equivalent. Indeed, if $sup_{x,y\in X}d(x,y)=\infty$ then you are looking for some $C \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $1\geq d'(x,y)\geq Cd(x,y)$, but since $d(x,y)$ is arbitrarily large, no such $C$ exists.

On the other hand, if $D=sup_{x,y\in X}d(x,y)<\infty$, you can take $c=1$ and $C=\frac{1}{D}$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. So the lemma is not "iff" therefore, the metrics $d,d'$ are topologically equiavlent but in this particular case, it's not Lipshitz equivalent then?

Comment: Yes, the lemma is not an "iff", and this is the actully the classical counterexample (when $sup_{x,y\in X}d(x,y)=\infty$).

Comment: wonderful, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is at least not the only issue, but there is

an ambiguity in their definition of Lipshitz equivalence.

> there exists $c,C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c,C>0$ and $cd(x,y) \geq d'(x,y) \geq Cd(x,y)$ $\forall x,y \in X$

could be interpreted as

> $\big[$there exists $c,C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c,C>0$ and $cd(x,y) \geq d'(x,y) \geq Cd(x,y)\big]$ $\forall x,y \in X$

or

> there exists $c,C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c,C>0$ and $\big[cd(x,y) \geq d'(x,y) \geq Cd(x,y)$ $\forall x,y \in X\hspace{.02 in}\big]$

.
(The latter is intended.)

In their definition,

> there exists $c,C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c,C>0$ and $cd(x,y) \geq d'(x,y) \geq Cd(x,y)$ $\forall x,y \in X$

should be replaced with

> and only if there exists $c,C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c,C>0$ and $\forall x,y \in X$, $cd(x,y) \geq d'(x,y) \geq Cd(x,y)$

.

Answer (score 0):

Note that given any real number $ε>0$, the balls $B_\delta(x)=\{y\in X \mid d(x,y)<\delta \}$ and $B'_δ(x) = \{ y\in X \mid d'(x,y)<δ \}$ are equal, where $δ=\min\{ε,1/ε\}$. So the metrics satisfy a somewhat weaker property than Lipschitz equivalence:

> Whenever you have two metrics $d$ and $d'$ such that for any $ε>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta \implies d'(x,y)<ε$ and $d'(x,y)<\delta\implies d(x,y)<ε$, we may call $d$ and $d'$ *uniformly equivalent*.

If $d$ and $d'$ are Lipschitz equivalent, they are also uniformly equivalent, with $\delta=\min\{ε/c,Cε\}$. And two uniformly equivalent metrics are topologically equivalent.
Your $d$ and $d'$ are not Lipschitz equivalent but only uniformly equivalent.